# Redirect website TLD under Azure Websites / DNS with parameter

Tags: azure, dns, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have registered a domain name for most, if not all, countries for my domain.  My website is running under Azure Websites.

What I am looking at doing is redirecting all `non-.com` domains to the `.com` domain, but including an additional parameter specifying the country and/or language (I am undecided on this, but it is the mechanism for getting this working that is the main point).

For example:

- User visits **example.com.au**, they are redirected to **example.com/au**
- User visits **example.co.uk**, they are redirected to **example.com/uk**
- User visits **example.com**, we append the country to give **example.com/us**

I believe that this might be able to be performed via URL rewrite rules plus the correct DNS entries, but not sure where to start.  In addition, does this allow me to get away with a single SSL certificate for the .com domain only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up implementing this via URL Rewrite rules.

```
<rules>
  <rule name="autocom" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com\.au"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/au/{R:1}" redirectType="Permament"/>
  </rule>
</rules>
```

The rule simply looks for the incoming host name, and redirects to my desired URL, appending the query string.

The DNS entries simply have an A record pointing to website, and the Azure Website knows about the `non-.com` domain name as well.

So far, this hasn't caused me any issues with regard to the SSL certificate - all browsers I tested have not shown their invalid SSL certificate warning(s).